# How can we use Tawk.to in React with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to use tawk.to in react with typescript and I installed their official npm package to add it in our website, but I am getting this error

```
import TawkMessengerReact from '@tawk.to/tawk-messenger-react';


Could not find a declaration file for module '@tawk.to/tawk-messenger-react'. 
'/Users/DrStrange/Desktop/supportapp/node_modules/@tawk.to/tawk-messenger-
react/dist/tawk-messenger-react.umd.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `tawk.d.ts` file and place `declare module '@tawk.to/tawk-messenger-react';` in it. this should work.